# Why is 'Subdivide' deselecting vertices instead of subdividing?

Tags: modeling

I know that subdivide is on right click in *Edit Mode* but for me it only deselects all vertices.

I already searched the whole Internet and everywhere is only by right clicking in *Edit Mode*.

Comment: Without any information provided by you others can only guess. Probably you use older version of Blender (2.7x) where right click select is used while you were expecting to have 2.8 where left click is used to select while right for menu (kinda industry standard). However rightclicking in edit mode cannot be shown as menu call on the whole internet since 2.8 is new and many articles are still about 2.7x

Comment: Subdivide was never under rightclick though, it was always and still is in 2.8 under W.

Comment: @Mzidare not necessarily. 2.8 is quite bad for troubleshooting in this context. If Select With is set to Left click then there is context menu on Right click where Subdivide resides and W executes Move mode. If Select With is set to Right click then W is reserved for opening Context menu since Right click is used to select.

Comment: You shouldn't be in Vertex mode, you want to be in Face mode or Edge mode.

Comment: @Mzidare, In 2.80, subdividing is done by right clicking on your mesh, and selecting **subdivide**.

Comment: @Millard Ok so Mr Zak is right and you Millard and I were incorrect cause there are two ways of doing that depending on what is set as "Select With". I'm comming from old Blender background so I assumed that the correct answer is the one for right click and you Millard are probably new to Blender and started with 2.8 so you assumed that the only right answer is for left click select.

Comment: no, I'm not new to blender, I just always set it to left click select.  In blender 2.79, I used the W shortcut to subdivide, but now in 2.80, you right click and select subdivide.

Comment: Oh, Mzidare must be using right click select.